# Javascript iterate an array with two conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have this array and these values:

```
const levels = [
    {
       name: 'first level primary school'     
    }, 
    {
       name: 'second level primary school'     
    },
    {
      name: 'first level secondary school'     
    }
]

const isPrimarySchool = false
const isSecondarySchool = false
```

And I want to iterate the array and find if there is a string with the word 'primary' or 'secondary' and turn the value of **isPrimarySchool** or **isSecondarySchool** to true.

The method that I found to resolve this, is this one:

```
levels.forEach(level => {
            if (
              level.name.toLowerCase().includes('primary')
            ) {
              isPrimarySchool = true
            }
            if (
              level.name.toLowerCase().includes('secondary')
            ) {
              this.isSecondarySchool = true
            }
          })
```

Is there a better way to resolve this, using lodash or normal javascript?

Comment: you can not reassign to a `const`. what result do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You could take a function for using with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and hand over the expected value.

```js
const
    has = string => o => o.name.includes(string),
    levels = [{ name: 'first level primary school' }, { name: 'second level primary school' }, { name: 'first level secondary school' }],
    isPrimarySchool = levels.some(has('primary')),
    isSecondarySchool = levels.some(has('second'))
    
console.log(isPrimarySchool);
console.log(isSecondarySchool);
```

Comment: nice usage of function currying!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to iterate the array and find if there is a string with the
> word 'primary' or 'secondary' and turn the value of isPrimarySchool or
> isSecondarySchool to true.

Using [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const levels = [
    {
       name: 'first level primary school'     
    }, 
    {
       name: 'second level primary school'     
    },
    {
      name: 'first level secondary school'     
    }
]
const isPrimarySchool = levels.some(x=>x.name.toLowerCase().includes('primary'))
const isSecondarySchool = levels.some(x=>x.name.toLowerCase().includes('secondary'))
console.log({isPrimarySchool,isSecondarySchool})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function and some regexp:

```js
isPrimarySchool = levels.some(level => /primary/.exec(level.name));
isSecondarySchool = levels.some(level => /secondary/.exec(level.name));
```